# How to find the code usage of the .properties resource(i18n) key in intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, internationalization

I have a xx.properties file which stores the key/value (used for i18n).
I know in Eclipse, if i click ctrl + 'key', it will jump to the java code where uses this key.

My question is:

- Does Intellij support this and how to do that?

Comment: Alt-F7?  IntelliJ also grays an entry out if it is determined not to be used in the project.

Comment: thanks, it works. @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F7</kbd>.  This is the general "Where is this used" key stroke for IntelliJ.

Note that IntelliJ grays an entry out if it thinks that it is not used in your current source code.